# what data type should i use to store email in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small website and I want to store the email of my contacts in a MySQL database.
I am using PHP and MySQL. Each time I try, it gives me following error. However when I remove the `@` and `.` (dot) it works fine. I really need a help on this one, please tell me what mistake I am doing and it would be very helpful if the code is given.

I already used `VARCHAR` only. It keeps showing up the error below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@gmail.com( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id),
>   name VARCHAR(3' at line 1

Comment: Can you paste the SQL query you are trying to run?

Comment: For email VARCHAR(50) (For MySQL) is ok for most of the cases.

Comment: ^ please do. as VARCHAR always works for me. Perhaps you haven't made the field large enough? I usually go with at least 50 characters.

Comment: use the varchar(50) datatype. but I think there is error in your query. so post the query.

Comment: Since that error code looks like part of a `CREATE TABLE` statement, you should post that, since your syntax is incorrect, not the fieldtype.

Comment: he won't be wrapping the email address in ' ' probably

Comment: THIS IS THE INSERT STATEMENT:

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, mail VARCHAR(50), password VARCHAR(30))")

Answer (score 7):

you can use `vachar` datatype with `1-255` length.

And for more information if your value's length is more then `255` then use `text` datatype

Answer (score 5):

Use varchar and wrap the email in quotes so it can be treated as a string like so:

'Email@gmail.com'

That's it bro.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the error with the @, you still have a query that won't work:
gmail.com( id INT....
shouldn't that be
gmail.com', ( id INT....?

The fact that your database can't handle a @ can be caused by the characterset of the database. Is it UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)?
And what is the type of the record where you want to store the mail?

Comment: The problem doesn't occurs when the @ and . are removed, so it's not a problem with varchar(50).

Answer (score 1):

a `varchar(50`) would be enough for storing email..

Then in your query all the values to insert must wrapped by `''` or `""`

e.g

```
$sql='INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES("Value1","EMAIL@GMAIL.com","VALUES3")'
```